# How to add methods dynamically inside a parallel.invoke

Tags: c#, parallel.invoke

Given below is the sample code.

```
            string[] str = new string[10];
            str[0] = "A";
            str[1] = "B";
            .... and so on.

            Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            {
                foreach(string temp in str)
                {
                MainFunc(temp);
                }

            });
```

I want to invoke the "MainFunc" methods 10 times dynamically. Hence, i used foreach loop for. But, the method is running only one time. Please help. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use `Parallel.ForEach()`.

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Parallel.Execute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx) executes each of the provided actions, possibly in parallel. In this case you have only one action, so it executes *only* once.

If you are looking for parallel call to each `str`  then use this.

```
 Parallel.ForEach(str, (temp) => 
 {
       MainFunc(temp);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You usage for Parallel.Invoke is incorrect. This method accepts one or more `Action`s and executes them in Parrallel. You're sending one Action only, so the 10 iteration executes one after the other. However, your `MainFunc` should run 10 times (based on the length of the string array.

To Execute the above logic in Parallel, use `Parallel.ForEach()`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(str, (temp) => MainFunc(temp));
```